# How to eliminate the arrows on this Cayley Graph

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs, tikz-graphs

I am trying to do the next graph, but without using arrows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,arrows.meta}

\newcount\quadrant
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
  \rule{A -> B [ R [A] [+A] [-A] ]}
  \symbol{R}{ \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep } 
  \symbol{-}{
\pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant+1,4)}
\tikzset{rotate=90}}
  \symbol{+}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant-1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=-90}
      }
\symbol{B}{
        \draw [dot-cayley] (0,0) -- (\pgflsystemstep,0) 
       node [font=\footnotesize, midway, 
         anchor={270-mod(\the\quadrant,2)*90}, inner sep=.5ex] 
       {\ifcase\quadrant$  $\or$ $\or$ $\or$ $\fi};
\tikzset{xshift=\pgflsystemstep}} }
\tikzset{
  dot/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.5pt,length=3pt]}, cayley/.tip={Stealth[]dot[]}    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[A] [+A] [-A] [++A], step=2cm, order=3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

But I want it without arrows. I don't know how to do this, I am new at this. Please help.

Comment: Just remove the `Stealth[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

Just remove `Stealth[]` here:

```
\tikzset{
  dot/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.5pt,length=3pt]}, cayley/.tip={Stealth[]dot[]}    }
```

---

complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,arrows.meta}

\newcount\quadrant
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{cayley}{
  \rule{A -> B [ R [A] [+A] [-A] ]}
  \symbol{R}{ \pgflsystemstep=0.5\pgflsystemstep } 
  \symbol{-}{
\pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant+1,4)}
\tikzset{rotate=90}}
  \symbol{+}{
    \pgfmathsetcount\quadrant{Mod(\quadrant-1,4)}
    \tikzset{rotate=-90}
      }
\symbol{B}{
        \draw [dot-cayley] (0,0) -- (\pgflsystemstep,0) 
       node [font=\footnotesize, midway, 
         anchor={270-mod(\the\quadrant,2)*90}, inner sep=.5ex] 
       {\ifcase\quadrant$  $\or$ $\or$ $\or$ $\fi};
\tikzset{xshift=\pgflsystemstep}} }
\tikzset{
  dot/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.5pt,length=3pt]}, cayley/.tip={dot[]}    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw l-system [l-system={cayley, axiom=[A] [+A] [-A] [++A], step=2cm, order=3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]